# Is std::is_standard_layout_v<T> always true if std::is_trivial_v<T> is true?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, type-traits

```
template<typename T>
void f()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_trivial_v<T>)
    {
        // Does the following line never fail?
        static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<T>); 
    }
}
```

1. Is `std::is_standard_layout_v<T>` always true if `std::is_trivial_v<T>` is true?
2. If no, is there any counterexamples?

Comment: You can see what the requirements are for those concepts, in the documentation: [TrivialType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType), [StandardLayoutType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

class type
{
    public: int x;
    private: int y;
};

static_assert(std::is_trivial_v< type >);
// not standard layout because different access level of x and y
static_assert(not std::is_standard_layout_v< type >);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xz3xLy